# Jquery - Regex to change color of Unicode characters in text?

Tags: jquery, regex, unicode

We have this... the simple version...
In the live version, "this" is inside of two jQuery each loops as we are searching multiple divisions for multiple unicode characters...

```
 <p id="searchDiv1">Root Juice&#8482;</p>
```

and we want to change the color of the "™" to red..
so we have this...

```
var char = '&#8482;';
var thisDiv = '#searchDiv1';

var replaceWithThis = '<span color="red">'+char+'</span>';
var newText = $(thisDiv).html().replace( /[char]/g, replaceWithThis);
$( thisDiv ).html(newText);
```

Unfortunately... the results look like this..

```
Root Jui™e™
```

Obviously... we need better regex... or something...
Anybody got any clues?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code. Here is a minimally modified version that works:

```js
var char = '\u2122';
var thisDiv = '#searchDiv1';
var replaceWithThis = '<font color="red">'+char+'</font>';
var newText = $(thisDiv).html().replace(new RegExp(char, 'g'), replaceWithThis);
$( thisDiv ).html(newText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="searchDiv1">Root Juice&#8482;</p>
```

First, you can’t use `&#8482;` in JavaScript, unless you make JavaScript parse it as HTML. Use the JavaScript character escape `\u2122` instead. Here 2122 is the hexadecimal form of decimal 8482.

Second, when you use `[char]` in a regexp, it is taken literally: it matches any of the characters c, h, a, r. No variable substitution takes place here. Use the `RegExp` constructor to build a regexp from the value of a variable.

Third, `span` elements do not have a `color` attribute. Use the `font` element instead. (It works just fine, even though many people frown upon it and curse it.) Alternatively, use e.g. a `span` element with a `class` attribute and define a CSS rule using that class. Or use inline CSS, `<span style="color: red">`.

Comment: Thanks JK... that all makes perfect sense...  Just one followup... is there a javascript function that converts the &#8442; to \u2122 ?  and yes... there are a bunch more that will need to be converted...

Comment: @BillWarren, you don’t need the `\u2122` then, you need the *character*, which you can get e.g. with `char = String.fromCharCode(8482)`. If you have the data in `&#8482;`, you need to do remove the extra characters or (less efficiently) assign such a string to the `innerHTML` property of a dummy HTML element, to get the string parsed as HTML.